# RegEx for replacing specific word and number pattern

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm looking for a way to find and remove a substring from the string based on a ***specific word *followed by* a number*** pattern.

**For Example :**

```
string = "These are 02 examples"
# Expected output : These examples

string = "Below are 2 examples"
# Expected output : Below examples

string = "Above are 05 examples"
# Expected output : Above examples
```

In the program I would be using this in, the word 'are' would remain static in all cases, only the number after it changes. Thanks.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.sub) to find a number with 1 or more digits following an `are` with one or more spaces in between via the regex `\s+are\s+\d+` and replace it with `are`, the below regex also takes care of spaces around `are` in the original word!

Also it's worth noting that you can compile the regex beforehand using [re.compile](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.compile)

```
import re

def change(s):

    pattern = re.compile('\s+are\s+\d+')
    return re.sub(pattern, ' are', s)

print(change("These are 02 examples"))
print(change("These are 2 examples"))
print(change("These are 05 examples"))
print(change("These are  05 examples"))
print(change("These are         05 examples  are 045 examples"))
```

The output will be

```
These are examples
These are examples
These are examples
These are examples
These are examples are examples
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand how to write regex, you should take a look at a website like [regexr](https://regexr.com/), which provide cheatsheets and many tools to learn.

Then you will use the `sub` method: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.sub

The regex you're looking for here is:

```
s2 = re.sub(r" are \d+", "", mystr)
```

**Update**: Or, if you want make it faster, compile the regex before:

```
rx = re.compile(r" are \d+")
s2 = rx.sub("", mystr)
```

Comment: I think you missed a space before and after `are`

Comment: since the regex is probably intended to be used several times, it could be nice to compile it

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex:

```
import re

text = """
These are 02 examples
Below are 2 examples
Above are 05 examples
"""

v = re.sub(r'are \d+', '', text)
print(v)
```

output:

```
These  examples
Below  examples
Above  examples
```